# Windows Form Controls - Font not changing for Wingding

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Windows Forms C# project to which I earlier added a button that used the Wingdings 3 font - and it worked. I've since created a new solution and tried the same thing but whenever I select Wingdings as the Font Name for any type of Windows Forms Control it always defaults to the Microsoft Sans Serif font in the Form Designer. For other fonts the Designer picks up  the changes.  I've also noticed that the same problem also ocurrs in my Visual Studio 2008 environment.

Could I have inadvertently changed an environment setting which disables fonts of certain type?

Comment: check fonts folder to make sure this font exists there Wingdings

Comment: The font exists in the C:\Windows\Fonts folder and it can also be used in Microsoft Word for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reasearching a little on stackoverflow, I come up with this unicode solution:

[Unicode alternative](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html)

Comment: Thanks I will try this just so I can move my development forwards but I'm still curious to find out why this would suddenly stop working for me.  Its a Windows forms app so I don't have to worry about the problems that non-standard fonts cause in certain web browsers.

Comment: Thanks Usman, I simply set the font name to Lucida Sans Unicode and then added buttonRefresh.Text = "\u21BB"; to my forms load event. This gave me the refresh symbol I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

In visual studio, click on the control and in the property section expand the font section.  Change the Font to Wingdings and the GdiCharSet value from 0 to 2.  Wingdings should be working for you then.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Hopefully your version has the same option.

Comment: This fixed my issue while following the Matching Game tutorial on MSDN - thank you!

Comment: where is GdiCharSet I cannot find it please ?

Comment: @ZiadAdnan, when you expand the font section, it should be one of the options listed.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with the label and Wingdings 2. Setting **UseCompatibleTextRendering** to **True** in the control properties worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this font though, it is not a standard font and hence not support by all applications. You may be able to find a standard Unicode alternative

[Wingdings font family does not seem to work on Firefox and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862569/wingdings-font-family-does-not-seem-to-work-on-firefox-and-opera)

Comment: It's a windows forms app so non-standard font such as wingdings should still work for me.

Answer (score 0):

gdicharset set to 1 (default) and it will be fixed. Don't move UseCompatibleTextRendering to true, leave it as false.